# Replace first elements of tuple with zero over a certain length

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, tuples

I have a sorted list based on first element:

```
A = [(0.11, '201405'), (0.41, '201402'),.....,(1.5, '201430')] # values and time
```

and want to change first element of each tuple:

```
x = len(C) # C is a list and its length is 2
y = len(D) # D is a list and its length is 1
if x > y:
    A[0[0:x]] = 0.0 # if x > y then set first element of A equal to zero (over length of C)
```

But I get following error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Please suggest to fix it.

Comment: Did you mean `A[0][0:x]`? At the moment, you have `0[0:x]`, which tries to slice an integer (which makes no sense, hence the `Typeerror`).

Comment: Tuples are unmodifyable; you'll have to create a new list with new tuples, e.g. using a list comprehension.

Comment: Ì think you need to go through a Python tutorial again. Especially the bit about loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to replace the first element in each of the first few tuples with `0`. Tuples are not modifyable, so you can not modify the existing tuples in the list, but you have to create a new list, holding new tuples. You can do this using a list comprehension.

Example:

```
>>> A = [(1,"a"), (2,"b"), (3,"c"), (4,"d")]
>>> A = [(x if i > 1 else 0, y) for i, (x, y) in enumerate(A)]
>>> print A
[(0, 'a'), (0, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'd')]
```

This will enumerate all the entries in the list, and for each entry create a tuple with the first element being `0`, if the index `i` of that entry is lower than some threshold, or the original value otherwise.

Comment: Glad that worked. Please know that if your list is really long you don't have to recreate the whole list. You can iterate through your existing list (again using enumerate) and just replace the element at position i with a new tuple. This is mostly just for the sake of completeness.

Comment: @blackpanda Agreed. +1

Answer (score 2):

1. As iharob mentioned, you have a subscript notation error.
2. Tuples are immutable. You can't just replace 1 element of the tuple in your list. You have to replace the whole tuple with another tuple containing 0.0 as first value and the existing second value. Note that lists are modifiable but tuples aren't. That's why you can update the list A, but you have to replace the tuple with a new tuple.

Here's an example that does not recreate the whole list:

```
for i, t in enumerate(A):
   if i < 1:
      A[i] = (0, t[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in `A[0[0:x]] = 0.0` you are using subscript notation for the number `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Furthermore, the tuple is an immutable type. Hence, it is impossible to change the content of a tuple. You'd better to generate a new list such as:

```
A = [0.0]+A[1:]
```